# What kind of line does this equation represent?

Tags: conic-sections

$x^2 – y^2 = -1$ . I know it is a hyperbola, but i want to know to reach this conclusion, (sorry for the symbols but I do not know how to use MathJax).

Comment: Wellcome to here. If you ask in details and contains your trials, then yo will get more beautiful feedback. And if you answer to other's question then you would get reputation and badges. Have a good time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's rewrite your equation as 
$$ (x+y)(x-y) = -1 $$
If we make a change of coordinates by setting 
$$ z := \frac{x-y}{\sqrt 2}, \quad w := \frac{x+y}{\sqrt 2} $$
(think of it as a rotation of the coordinate system by $45^°$), we have in our new coordinates 
$$ wz = -2 \iff z = -\frac 2w, $$
which describes a hyperbola.

Comment: Why dividing each factor by 2, means a rotation of coordinate system by 45 degrees?

Comment: The $z = 0$-line, that is the "$w$-axis", is the line, where $x=y$, which is a $45^°$ rotated $x$-axis. The $\sqrt 2$-factors are here to make the transformation lenght preserving (we want the point with $(z,w)$-corrdinates $(1,0)$ to have distance 1 from the origin.